# jquery datepicker problem in include page in php

Tags: php, jquery

I use the following `datepicker.php` page for jquery datepicker is given below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">  
<input type="text" id="datepicker" />
</body>
</html>
```

it is working well as a single page but when i use this page from another page using include (`datepicker.php`) method then the datepicker is not working. How can I solve this?

Comment: Not sure this is the issue... but are you aware that you're including multiple versions of both jQuery and jQueryUI?

Comment: Try viewing the rendered source of the page in the browser.  Make sure all of the links to js and css files are valid, and that you don't have multiple elements with the same id.  If you're not using Firebug, use it and check for js errors when the page loads.

Comment: It looks like you have an extra close script tag in column 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this function used only one page if you use datepicker on another page then define function on another page.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be including a full HTML document within another HTML document. The result is not a valid webpage.